# Finding multiple local minimum

Tags: functions, mathematical-optimization

I have the following code:

```
sol = NDSolve[{v1'[t] == 
16.5*(v2[t] - 
   v1[t] - (-0.714*v1[t] + 
     0.5*(-1.143 + 0.714)*(Abs[v1[t] + 1] - Abs[v1[t] - 1]))),  v2'[t] == v1[t] - v2[t] + i[t], i'[t] == -35*v2[t], v1[0] == 0.7,  v2[0] == 0, i[0] == 0}, {v1, v2, i}, {t, 0, 100}]
V1[t_] = v1[t] /. sol
Plot[V1[t], {t, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"t", "V1"}]
FindMinValue[V1[t], t]
```

So my problem is that I would need the value of every local minimum of this oscillating function. I tried reading these forums, but I'm a newbie to mathematica, so some explanations were beyond my understanding. Can you give me some hints or help, so I can get the values of the minimums? I have 7.0 version.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find the values for the v1 minima we can proceed as follows

```
T = {};
sol = NDSolve[{v1'[t] == 16.5*(v2[t] - v1[t] - (-0.714*v1[t] + 0.5*(-1.143 + 0.714)*(Abs[v1[t] + 1] - Abs[v1[t] - 1]))), 
               v2'[t] == v1[t] - v2[t] + i[t], 
                i'[t] == -35*v2[t], 
                v1[0] == 0.7, 
                v2[0] == 0, 
                i[0] == 0, 
      WhenEvent[v1'[t] == 0, If[v1[t] < 1.5, AppendTo[T, {t, v1[t]}]]]}, {v1, v2, i}, {t, 0, 100}]
```

so in T we will have all the minima locations.

```
V1[t_] = v1[t] /. sol
gr1 = Plot[V1[t], {t, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"t", "V1"}]
gr2 = ListPlot[T, PlotStyle -> Red];
Show[gr1, gr2]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I saw you put v1[t]<1.5 in the logical expression of the 'If' command. Can you tell me, why can't I use v1''[t]>0? If I'm right, that is a criterion for a minimum in function analysis, I tried to add it, but that way it doesn't find any minimum.

Comment: In the equation for **v1** as **v1'[t] = f(v1[t],v2[t])** if **f(.)** were derivable regarding **t** then we could write the condition as **WhenEvent[v1'[t]==0,If[H > 0,Append[...]]]** where **H = D[f(v1[t],v2[t]),t]** but **f** has inside the function **Abs[]** ....

Comment: But @SirAndre66 , be aware, that the minima beyond t > 35, you get this way with MachinePrecision, are totaly wrong. for comparison `//Rationalize[#,0]& ` the equations and apply `WorkingPrecision -> 50 ` to see the difference. (may be `MaxSteps -> 10^5 ` )

Comment: to @Cesareo , please see comment above.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have access to version 7 so I cannot verify that this will work; however, I believe that it will.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

sol = NDSolve[{v1'[t] == 
      16.5*(v2[t] - 
         v1[t] - (-0.714*v1[t] + 
           0.5*(-1.143 + 0.714)*(Abs[v1[t] + 1] - Abs[v1[t] - 1]))), 
     v2'[t] == v1[t] - v2[t] + i[t], i'[t] == -35*v2[t], v1[0] == 0.7, 
     v2[0] == 0, i[0] == 0}, {v1, v2, i}, {t, 0, 100}][[1]];
```

`V1` should be restricted to numeric arguments

```
V1[t_?NumericQ] := v1[t] /. sol;

tmax = 100;
```

Using brute force search, the local minimum in the interval `{0, tmax}` are

```
pts = Sort[{t /. #[[2]], #[[1]]} & /@ 
     Union[N[FindMinimum[{V1[t], 0 <= t <= tmax}, {t, #}, 
          WorkingPrecision -> 15]] & /@ Range[0, tmax, 1/10],
      SameTest -> (Abs[#1[[2, 1, -1]] - #2[[2, 1, -1]]] < 10^-3 &)]] // Quiet;
```

The brute force search resulted in many duplicates so they were removed with [`Union`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Union.html). Looking at the first few results

```
pts[[1 ;; 5]]

(* {{5.40409*10^-7, 0.700001}, {1.16966, 0.906126}, {2.52891, 
  0.239197}, {3.92568, -0.137409}, {5.20191, 0.6936}} *)
```

The [`Plot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html) with the minimums highlighted:

```
Plot[V1[t], {t, 0, tmax},
 PlotRange -> All,
 AxesLabel -> {"t", "V1"},
 PlotPoints -> 200,
 MaxRecursion -> 7,
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4], Point[pts]},
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, it works on 7.0 also, but it runs for a very long time, I have 12.0 on my office computer and it takes about 30 seconds.

Comment: I arbitrarily choose a very dense sampling, i.e., `Range[0, tmax, 1/10]`; however, this is overkill for this specific function. It will go faster if you take larger steps, e.g., `Range[0, tmax, 1/2]`; however, as you increase the step size you need to check that you are not missing any of the local minima.